# Using Windows Authentication for Authorization ASPNET CORE 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I want to implement authorization so that a user gets a totally different view based on their level of access.

Using the user's username `@User.Identity.Name` and a SQL Table would define the level of access that the user has.

In other words, if we have an Admin user, they will have access to all parts of the application. However, if it is a user, they will be limited  to certain parts.

On the SQL table it would have the username and their role:

Username | Role

Domain/Admin | Admin

Domain/User | User

Then ASP net would handle the roles native in the Controller.

Comment: What's the question? By the way, I definitely *would not* use username as a key to determine the users role. Why not determine the role via an AD group?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?  I'm looking to do similar.  But based on my research so far, using Windows Authentication but managing authorisation at an application level is not a common scenario.  I haven't come on worked through examples on how to do this so am trying to put it together - I don't know whether you've seen this, but that's what I'm wading through among other things:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/?view=aspnetcore-2.1